# illegal instruction in stdc++

Tags: linux, gcc

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello world " << 1234 << "\n";
    std::string str = ss.str();
    printf(str.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
CC=/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2/bin/g++
CFLAGS=-g -c -W -m32 -Wa,-mtune=pentiumiii
LINKFLAGS=-m32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-rpath,./runtime,--dynamic-linker,./runtime/ld-linux.so.2
all:test
test: list_test.o
    $(CC) $(LINKFLAGS) list_test.o -o test 

list_test.o: list_test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) list_test.cpp

clean:
     rm *.o ./test -f
```

I build it in 64-bit linux. there is an illegal instruction when it run in 32-bit linux with pentinum(R) III cpu.

the illegal instruction is as follow:

```
(gdb) disas 0x0804f77a 0x0804f77b
Dump of assembler code from 0x804f77a to 0x804f77b:
0x0804f77a <std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::char_type*, std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::__size_type, std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::__size_type)+138>:     movq   %xmm0,0xc(%esp)
```

End of assembler dump.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I believe the `-Wa,` is useless in your `CFLAGS`, should be `CFLAGS=-g -Wall -m32 -mtune=pentiumiii`

Comment: /usr/local/gcc-4.6.2/bin/g++ -g -c -W -m32 -mno-sse -mtune=pentiumiii list_test.cpp
list_test.cpp:1:0: error: bad value (pentiumiii) for -mtune= switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `movq   %xmm0,0xc(%esp)` is part of the [Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instruction set.  The Pentium III in theory supports SSE, but the processor you're trying to run it in apparently doesn't.  You can disable the generation of SSE instructions on GCC with the [`-mno-sse`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#index-mno_002dsse-1484) compiler option.  You can also try [`-march=pentium3`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) to generate code compatible with Pentium III and above.

Also, your `printf` call has a bug—you should (almost) never pass a non-constant string as the format argument (the first argument).  If that string happens to contain any `%` signs in it, that will lead to undefined behavior.  At best, this will crash, and at worst, you could have a silent security vulnerability.  The fix is to do this:

```
printf("%s", str.c_str());
```

Or better yet, avoid the potential problems with the `printf` family of functions entirely, since you're using C++:

```
std::cout << str;  // Optionally also do `<< std::flush'
```

Comment: I tryed use -mno-sse compiler option,but it doesn't work!
It can't be compiled by using -mcpu=pentium3, the error is as follow:
g++: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead
list_test.cpp:1:0: error: bad value (pentinumiii) for -mtune= switch

Comment: @JianZhang: Try `-march=` instead of `-mcpu=`.

Comment: Note that that particular instruction may in fact be in one of the libraries that are linked in, not in the code generated from your source file. If that is the case, you will need to rebuild the entire library with appropriate options to avoid the unsupported instructions. Better yet, just do the build on your target system, that already has properly functioning libraries on it...

Comment: Yes, the unsupported instructions is in libstdc++ libraries, the problem is resolved by using an old version of libstdc++. thanks for all your help! @AdamRosenfield

Comment: @JianZhang: Why are you staticly linking libstdc++ in the first place?  If you used dynamic linking (the default), then you wouldn't have this problem, since the shared library for libstdc++ on the target machine would never have instructions in it which were illegal on that machine.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Valid point, but running a binary compiled with a newer library on a system with an older library *may* run into issues for libraries that contain versioned symbols - a common problem with `glibc` at least, not sure if it is for `libstdc++`... That's one possible reason for wanting a static link...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a SSE instruction, which is apparently not supported by the processor. (Pentium 3 is supposed to support SSE though).

You can try compiling your code with `-mno-sse` and see if it helps.